# RIDE's output cannot display status of test cases

Tags: robotframework

I found that if my scipt contain any Chinese characters, it works good and statu is "PASS", but RIDE's output will no display the status of cases.
Here is my code:

```
*** Test Cases ***
test
    [Template]
    Log To Console    中文
```

And here is the output: ======[Link of screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxjQ0.jpg)=======

---

```
command: pybot.bat --outputdir ./report/ --argumentfile c:\users\figoto~1\appdata\local\temp\RIDEqvnd6h.d\argfile.txt --listener D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\contrib\testrunner\TestRunnerAgent.py:61768:False E:\testing\PartnerAutoTest\Partner
========================================================================================================================================================================
Partner                                                                                                                                                                 
========================================================================================================================================================================
Partner.Landing                                                                                                                                                         
========================================================================================================================================================================
Log:     E:\testing\PartnerAutoTest\Partner\report\log.html
Report:  E:\testing\PartnerAutoTest\Partner\report\report.html

test finished 20160304 16:13:00
```

---

When my script contans no Chinese character, the output is fine, like this:

```
*** Test Cases ***
test
    [Template]
    Log To Console    Chinese
```

And output like this:===========[Link of Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8euU.jpg)===========

---

```
command: pybot.bat --outputdir ./report/ --argumentfile c:\users\figoto~1\appdata\local\temp\RIDEqvnd6h.d\argfile.txt --listener D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\contrib\testrunner\TestRunnerAgent.py:61768:False E:\testing\PartnerAutoTest\Partner
========================================================================================================================================================================
Partner                                                                                                                                                                 
========================================================================================================================================================================
Partner.Landing                                                                                                                                                         
========================================================================================================================================================================
Partner.Landing.Debug test                                                                                                                                              
========================================================================================================================================================================
test                                                                                                                                                            Chinese
| PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test2                                                                                                                                                           | FAIL |
chinese
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Partner.Landing.Debug test                                                                                                                                      | FAIL |
2 critical tests, 1 passed, 1 failed
2 tests total, 1 passed, 1 failed
========================================================================================================================================================================
Partner.Landing                                                                                                                                                 | FAIL |
2 critical tests, 1 passed, 1 failed
2 tests total, 1 passed, 1 failed
========================================================================================================================================================================
Partner                                                                                                                                                         | FAIL |
2 critical tests, 1 passed, 1 failed
2 tests total, 1 passed, 1 failed
========================================================================================================================================================================
Output:  E:\testing\PartnerAutoTest\Partner\report\output.xml
Log:     E:\testing\PartnerAutoTest\Partner\report\log.html
Report:  E:\testing\PartnerAutoTest\Partner\report\report.html

test finished 20160304 16:23:34
```

---

All I know is everything was fine before I upgrade RIDE and Robotframework yesterday. (for DateTime library)
Here is my version now:
RIDE 1.5.2.1 running on Python 2.7.9. 
robotframework-3.0

Maybe I need to change some encoding files somewhere. So I tried to change the file  "D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\robotide\lib\robot\utils\encodingsniffer.py" , but it didn't work.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My friend told me to Edit this file and it worked.

Python27\Lib\site-packages\robotide\contrib\testrunner\testrunner.py

```
def pop(self):
    ...........(ignore this...)
    try:
        result=result.decode('UTF-8')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        pass
    return result
```